# PHP SoapClient: How to prefix SOAP parameter tag name with namespace?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm using PHP's `SoapClient` to consume a SOAP service but am receiving an error that the SOAP service cannot see my parameters.

```
<tns:GenericSearchResponse xmlns:tns="http://.../1.0">
  <tns:Status>
    <tns:StatusCode>1</tns:StatusCode>
    <tns:StatusMessage>Invalid calling system</tns:StatusMessage>
  </tns:Status>
</tns:GenericSearchResponse>
```

The XML PHP's SoapClient sends for the SOAP call:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://.../1.0">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GenericSearchRequest>
      <UniqueIdentifier>12345678</UniqueIdentifier>
      <CallingSystem>WEB</CallingSystem>
    </ns1:GenericSearchRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I used soap-ui initially, that works successfully when consuming the same WSDL. The XML soap-ui sends for the call:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://.../1.0">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GenericSearchRequest>
      <ns1:UniqueIdentifier>12345678</ns1:UniqueIdentifier>
      <ns1:CallingSystem>WEB</ns1:CallingSystem>
    </ns1:GenericSearchRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The difference being the `UniqueIdentifier` and `CallingSystem` parameters are prefixed with `ns1` in the soap-ui request.

I've tried using passing `SoapVar` objects to the `SoapClient` call but this does not augment the parameter tags and prefix them with `ns1`.

I know that `WEB` is a valid `CallingSystem` value as the XSD specifies it, and it works when using soap-ui.

My current `SoapClient` code:

```
try {
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
  $query = new stdClass;
  $query->UniqueIdentifier = $id;
  $query->CallingSystem = 'WEB';
  $response = $client->GenericUniqueIdentifierSearch($query);
} catch (SoapFault $ex) {
  $this->view->error = $ex->getMessage();
  ...
}
```

I found [this blog post](http://eosrei.net/articles/2012/01/php-soap-xml-attributes-namespaces-xmlwriter) but I was hoping there might be a cleaner implementation.

**Update:**
Used a [solution from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10932943/122075) but is pretty clunky:

```
$xml = "<ns1:GenericSearchRequest>"
     . "<ns1:UniqueIdentifier>$id</ns1:UniqueIdentifier>"
     . "<ns1:CallingSystem>WEB</ns1:CallingSystem>"
     . "</ns1:GenericSearchRequest>";
$query = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);

$response = $this->client->__SoapCall(
    'GenericUniqueIdentifierSearch',
    array($query)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [SoapVar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php) to namespace the `GenericSearchRequest` fields:

```
$xml = "<ns1:GenericSearchRequest>"
     . "<ns1:UniqueIdentifier>$id</ns1:UniqueIdentifier>"
     . "<ns1:CallingSystem>WEB</ns1:CallingSystem>"
     . "</ns1:GenericSearchRequest>";
$query = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);

$response = $this->client->__SoapCall(
    'GenericUniqueIdentifierSearch',
    array($query)
);
```

Answer (score 7):

The reasonable way I found to do this, is to use a combination of SoapVar and SoapParam.

Note, SoapVar has options to specify the namespace of each var.

So your code should be something like:

```
$wrapper = new StdClass;
$wrapper->UniqueIdentifier = new SoapVar($id, XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "UniqueIdentifier", "ns1");
$wrapper->CallingSystem = new SoapVar("WEB", XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "CallingSystem", "ns1");
$searchrequest = new SoapParam($wrapper, "GenericSearchRequest");

try{
    $response = $this->client->GenericUniqueIdentifierSearch($searchrequest);
}catch(Exception $e){
    die("Error calling method: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

If you get an issue where the attributes and the method are getting different namespaces, try specifying the namespace for your SoapVar as the url as defined in your envelope (in your example: "http://.../1.0") like:

```
$wrapper->UniqueIdentifier = new SoapVar($id, XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "UniqueIdentifier", "http://.../1.0");
```

See the [Soap constants](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soap.constants.php) for a list of all XSD_* constants.